# Anchor framwork with vanilla js

Tags: anchor

I'm doing a web extension and we are not using any framework for that, we are developing with vanilla JS. First, we were using only Solana web3 with borsh and bip libraries. For the first a minified standalone is already provided by the team, for the others we used browserify for it. Happens that after some experiments we are using now anchor on our smart contracts and we wanted to use anchor library to make it easy to develop the client side. We did some experiences with node and it really works well, but now that we are trying to implement it on our WE we weren't able to have a good result using browserify. It returns some errors on we try to call a method from the program. So my question is. There is really no standalone version of the library? Does someone use browserify for this with success?

Thank you for the attention
Best regards,
Miguel Fonseca

Answer (score 1):

I've been having some good luck with Browserify recently, though just in the early alpha phases of developing my project. I added the following line to the top of my JS file before running Browserify:

`const solanaWeb3 = require("@solana/web3.js");`

I've also tried to use the Tinyify plugin but haven't had much success yet. If you have any updates on your experience I'm all ears!